# Swift assuming generic type when used recursively

Tags: swift, generics

Simple enough example:

```swift
protocol Fulfilment {
}

class Node<T: Fulfilment> {
    var object: T
    var children: [Node]

    init(object: T, children: [Node] = []) {
        self.object = object
        self.children = children
    }
}

struct One: Fulfilment {
}

struct Two: Fulfilment {
}

let node1 = Node<One>(object: One())
let node2 = Node<Two>(object: Two(), children: [node1])
```

I get an error on the last line because `node1` isn't of type `Two` even though I didn't specify the generic type should be applied to `children`. The compiler is treating the code as though I wrote

`var children: [Node<T>]`

The assumption that I want to conform to the same generic type is causing me a headache. Can I somehow tell Swift that I do not want this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that there is no such type `Node` without a specific generic type parameter and specialised versions of `Node`, such as `Node<One>` and `Node<Two>` are completely unrelated types, so you couldn't store an array of `Node`s with different `object` types anyways. Hence the compiler inferring `children` to be of type `Node<T>`.